# Finding Exponential Generating Series for Number of Functions from $A$ to $B$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm kind of confused how to solve this problem:

> Find the exponential generating series for the number of functions 
>   $f: A → B$ where $A = \{1, 2, 3 ,\dots, n\}$ and $B = \{1, 2, 3, \dots, m\} $ such that the preimage set of every element of $B$ is at least size four?

i.e. # $f^{-1}(j) \geq 4$ for each $j \in B$

Comment: Confused about what? What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I'm kind of confused how to even approach this problem

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Read the examples (3) and (4) in the document [exponential](https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/exponential.pdf).

Example (3) is about the exponential generating function for the number of functions from $A$ to $B$ (with $|A|=n$ and $|B|=m$). It means that the preimage set of every element of $B$ has at least size ZERO. Such e.g.f. is
$$F(x)=(e^x)^m.$$

Example (4) is about the exponential generating function for the number of functions from $A$ to $B$  which are surjective. It means that the preimage set of every element of $B$ has at least size ONE. Such e.g.f. is
$$F(x)=(e^x-1)^m.$$

Moreover, the question [The total number of ways to put $N$ distinct balls into $K$ distinct boxes so that every box has more than one ball (assuming that $N \geqslant 2K$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252476/the-total-number-of-ways-to-put-n-distinct-balls-into-k-distinct-boxes-so-th) is related to the case when the preimage set of every element of $B$ has at least size TWO.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: @memesnotdreams Are you still confused? Is my answer of any help? Please explain your doubts.